# Issue with "Join attributes by field value" on QGIS 3.4.7

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-joins, qgis-modeler

I have a shape file with polygons and a xlsx sheet, and I need to join their tables using Join attributes by field value in the modeler.

At QGIS 2.18 it works perfectly, but in 3.4.7 the join doesn't work, but if I do a manual join at the properties of the shape, the join happens normally.

I´m looking for some help with this tool to use **in the modeler**.

Both colums have the same type and size. I already tried to reinstall QGIS and tried on different machines.

Here are some prints to shows the issue.

[image]
The tables I want to join by the field FUNDO.

[image]
Set up for the join.

[image]
Nothing could be matched.

[image]

Set up for the manual join.

[image]
Everything is joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the auto-detected type of the joinig field in the xls-table did not match the field type of the shp (table: string; shp:integer). Calculated a new field in the shp in string-format with integer-to-string conversion of the data. 
Result: String-field (xls) <-> String-Field(shp)

Comment: When I use the "Join attribute by field value"  on the same inputs on the QGIS platform it works well. However when I use the same inputs with the same tools in the processing modeler, then it fails.