# QGIS 3.4 using pygis for deleting colomns

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, qgis-3

I am currently building a model for importing and preparing multiple data by merging shapes and joining tables.

Almost finished with the model, but I haven't found a useful tool for deleting certain columns of an attribute table in the graphical modeler.

So I am right now stuck in writing myself a tool for this purpose and unfortunately I am not that experienced in writing code.

I just need to delete following indexes - Always the same ones.

eg. :[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,19,20,22,23,24,25,27,28,29,41,42,44,45]

edit: Code:

```
layer=Qgs.utils.iface.activeLayer()

layer_provider.deleteAttributes([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,19,20,22,23,24,25,27,28,29,41,42,44,45])
layer.updateFields()
```

edit2: I tried to make a dropdown menu using an existing code from [J. Monticolo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321597/where-to-get-qgis-3-join-by-field-value-script) It did not work, as expected..

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class MyModel2(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('inputlayer1', 'input_layer_1', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVector], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Output_layer', 'output_layer', optional=True, type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        layer=QgsVectorLayer('input_layer_1')
        with edit(layer)
            layer.deleteAttributes([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,19,20,22,23,24,25,27,28,29,41,42,44,45])

        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'delete_table'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'delete_table'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return MyModel2()
```

Comment: Please, add what you have so far for understand your code

Comment: If you have a working model, in QGIS 3.6, you can export it as Python code : https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog36/index.html#feature-resurrected-model-to-python-script-functionality

Comment: Alright, that seems to very useful! Will get the 3.6 Version then as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
layer=QgsVectorLayer(r'C:\Test\Cities.shp')

with edit(layer):
    layer.deleteAttributes([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,19,20,22,23,24,25,27,28,29,41,42,44,45])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What else do I have to add-that this code works as a stand alone tool? So that I can use it for the graphical modeler?

Comment: @Emu nice! Please accept my answer with the checkbox if it solved your problem. Not sure, you can post that as a new question and include the code you try with.

Comment: thanks for the advise, I will make a new submission!